# Hardy–Littlewood Tauberian theorem for Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, tauberian-theory

The Hardy–Littlewood Tauberian theorem for Laplace transform in Chapter XIII in "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications" by Feller reads as follows

Let $F : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ of bounded variation, $p \geq 0$ be real number and
$$\omega_F(s) = \int^\infty_0 e^{-st} d F(t).$$
Then each of the relations
$$ \dfrac{\omega_F(\tau \lambda)}{\omega_F(\tau)} \to \lambda^{-p}\hspace{15pt} \text{as $\tau \to 0$}.$$
$$ \dfrac{F(tx)}{F(t)} \to x^{p} \hspace{15pt} \text{as $t \to \infty$}.$$
implies the other as well as
$$ \omega_F(1/t) \sim F(t) \Gamma(p+1) \hspace{15pt} \text{as $t \to \infty$}.$$

I have two questions. Firstly, I am so doubt that if the statement is true for $p=0$. It seems that the inverse  Laplace transform of $1$ is $\delta(t)$. In this case is it true that $\dfrac{\omega_F(\tau \lambda)}{\omega_F(\tau)} \to 1$ implies $\dfrac{F(tx)}{F(t)} $ converging to the Heaviside step function rather $1$?

The second question is that do we have the Tauberian theorem for the Laplace transform in form of $F(s) = \displaystyle\int^\infty_0 e^{-st} f(t) dt$, namely the asymptotic relation of $F$ and $f$. Thanks!!!